# Passing strings to a React function

Tags: reactjs

I have created a simple function to accept the parameters name and email, and display them on screen.

Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const datarow = props => <div><b>Name:{props.myname}</b><br></br><b>Email:{props.email}</b></div>;

function App() {
  return <datarow myname='James' email='james@place.org' />;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

When I execute this within CodeSandbox however, the resulting page is blank. No compile errors are occurring. What am I doing wrong? My expectation is I should be able to pass name and email into this function and get a result on-screen.

Comment: return the div in data row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Components Should always be on Camel Cases

Check Documentation Here: https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#components

Change your code to this instead:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const DataRow = props => <div><b>Name:{props.myname}</b><br></br><b>Email:{props.email}</b></div>;

function App() {
  return <DataRow myname='James' email='james@place.org' />;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I can't believe that's all it was! I'm used to a strongly typed and rigid language like C# so you'd think I would have picked that up :P But I hear all this talk about things like React, node and python being all fluid and free and relaxed, so I guess I didn't even think that casing could be the cause. Thanks Bon! And everyone else who replied :)

Comment: `Datarow` is not camel case. `DataRow` is.

Answer (score 0):

A react component has to start with an upper case letter.

Change it to:

```
const DataRow = (props) => <div><b>Name:{props.myname}</b><br></br><b>Email:{props.email}</b></div>;

const App = () => <DataRow myname='James' email='james@place.org'/>;
```